# Have Jenkins read the contents of the table in Confluence page

Tags: jenkins, confluence

I got only a basic knowledge of the jenkins. I want to be able to read the contents of the table from a confluence page and then print it. Any references will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to utilize the Confluence [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/) and write some Groovy code or a shell script within a declarative Pipeline to retrieve whatever you need.